# How can i make a destroy button for my chart in JavaScript? (Chart.js)

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I am trying to make a button that clears/destroys the chart in the canvas so that i can make a new one on the same canvas, but i keep on getting that my function is declared but its value is never read. How can i fix this? I will share alot of my code under so its easier to help me, but the code messy.

HTML:

```
        <!--Canvas for chart-->
        <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
        <!-- https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/ -->
        <script id="graph1" type="text/JavaScript" src="js/Main.js"></script>     
        
        <button type="button" id="generate" onclick="generateGraph()">Generate</button>
        <button type="button" id="clear" onclick="clearCanvas()">Clear</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
//Url for JSON-file
var url = "";
//The labels for the chart
var graphLabels = [];

var generateButton = document.getElementById("generate");

//When a checkbox is checked (function)
function generateGraph(url) {
  var arrayTheta = [];
  var arrayRange = [];
  var mcsArray = [];
  var channelArray = [];
  
  //Getting the data from json-file (function) {NOTE: gotta figure out a way to get data from multible JSON-files}
  async function getData(arrayRange, arrayTheta, url, graphLabels, mcsArray, channelArray) {  

    //Gets data from the JSON-file, were the url is the box that is checked
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const productData = await response.json();


    for (let index = 0; index < productData.length; index++) {
      arrayTheta.push(productData[index].theta);
      arrayRange.push(productData[index].Range);
    }


    //The graph, copied from Chart.js, but changed for our prefrence
    const ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
    const myChart = new Chart(ctx,{
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: arrayTheta,
            datasets: [{
                label: graphLabels,
                data: arrayRange,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',

                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                pointRadius: 0,
                tension: 0.4
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
                ,x: {
                  display: true,
                  type: 'linear'
                }
            }
        }
    });
    
  }


  getData(arrayRange, arrayTheta, url, graphLabels, mcsArray, channelArray)
  

  //Trying to make a clear button, but does not work (Remove this comment when it works)
  var clearButton = document.getElementById("clear")
    
  function clearCanvas() {
    console.log("DETROYINGG")
    myChart.destroy()
    
  }
}
```

I hope this code is enough to help me, but if you need more i can send that too.

Answer (score 0):

your `const myChart` declaration is inside `generateGraph` function, only the code inside `generateGraph` has access to `const myChart`

what you could do is to use `window.myChart` instead of `const myChart` so that the variable is globally available and you `clearCanvas()` function can access it also using `window.myChart.destroy()`

Comment: I tried it now, and it might help with a problem that i didnt know existed, but i still get the same error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: clearCanvas is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:170:70)

Comment: The error takes me too the button-tag:
            <button type="button" id="clear" onclick="clearCanvas()">Clear</button>

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to tag you

Comment: your clearCanvas() is inside the generateGraph() function so to access it form the global scope you need to do generateGraph.clearCanvas()
Given the window.myChart approach it is better to move the clearCanvas() function in the global scope at the same level of generateGraph() so that you can call it directly like you are actually doing in the onclick hanlder.